# Is there an algorithm to link points, that minimises Manhattan length?

Tags: algorithm, tree, geometry

I'm trying to link points in the plane, ie draw a graph, but using only axis-aligned lines. I found the KDTree algorithm

[image: KDTreeExample]

to be quite promising and close to what I need
but it does not make sure the segments are as small as possible.
The result I'm looking for is closer to

[image: ImprovedKDTree]

I have also read up on
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation
because initially, I thought that would be it;
but it turns out its way off:
- based on circles and triangles
- traces a perimeter
- nodes have multiple connections (>=3)

Can you point me towards an algorithm that already exists?
or can you help me with drafting a new algorithm?

PS: Only 1000-1100 points so efficiency is not super important.
In terms of Goals and Costs, reaching all nodes is the Goal
and the length of all segments is the Cost.

Comment: [For reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_Steiner_tree)

Comment: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: Another stumble into an NP-hard problem.

Comment: It's too little for an answer - link describes a problem but don't solve it completely, and  I cannot add useful proposals.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [MBo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844416/mbo), I now know that this is known as 'The Steiner Tree Problem'. This is the subject of a 1992 book (of the same name) demonstrating that it is an NP-hard problem.

This is the Rectilinear variant of that. There are a few approximate algorithms or heuristic algorithms known to (help) solve it.

( HAN, HAN4, LBH, HWAB, HWAD, BEA are listed inside
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9390010L )

I haven't found anything yet that a "practitioner" might be able to actually use. Still looking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a 'good' way forward is:

1. Compute edges using [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).
2. Label each edge with its length or rectilinear distance.
3. Find the [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree) (with algorithms such as Borůvka's, Prim's, or Kruskal's).
4. Add [Steiner points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem) restricted to the [Hanan grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanan_grid).
5. Move edges to the grid.

Still unclear about that last step. How?